# ARP-cache table update

Tags: router, arp

Do routers update the ARP entry in their ARP-cache table when receiving the gratuitous ARP request/reply from a neighbour host?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes.  Just like every other IP host.